# JavaScript: Is there a function to remove item from array if found duplicate values in specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with three columns:

```
[ '27', 'Name', '1' ],
[ '27', 'Name', '1' ],
[ '27', 'Name', '1' ],
[ '27', 'Name', '2' ]
```

I am trying to remove the item that has duplicates in the third column so I get:

```
[ '27', 'Name', '2' ]
```

I am using this code:

```
  function getUniqueListBy(arr, key) {
    return [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
  }

let newArray = getUniqueListBy(myArr, '2');
```

And it does a very good job removing the duplicates, but I'd like to remove the item (the one that had duplicated) too. If possible, I'd like the code to be as efficient as possible. How can I do that?

Comment: so, i f you had `['28, 'Other Name', '1']` would that also need to be filtered out, as it is a duplicate in the 3rd column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Map:** You can create a map of elements at index `2` and store the value as an array of `index` that contains the same value at that index.

It is a dictionary of elements that contains the same element at the `2` index.

**filter:** Filter the result and lookup in the dictionary if element at the `2` index's array length should be `1`

```js
const arr = [
  ["27", "Name", "1"],
  ["27", "Name", "1"],
  ["27", "Name", "1"],
  ["27", "Name", "2"],
];

// [ '27', 'Name', '2' ]
const map = new Map();

// na is nestedArray
arr.forEach((na, i) => {
  const value = na[2];
  if (map.has(value)) map.get(value).push(i);
  else map.set(value, [i]);
});

const result = arr.filter((na, i) => map.get(na[2]).length === 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you stringify the subarrays (which allows for easy comparison with `===` and `Set#has`), you can use two Sets to easily identify which items are duplicates, so they get removed.

```js
const arr = [
[ '27', 'Name', '1' ],
[ '27', 'Name', '1' ],
[ '27', 'Name', '1' ],
[ '27', 'Name', '2' ]
];
const found = new Set();
const dupes = new Set();
for (const subarr of arr) {
  const str = JSON.stringify(subarr);
  if (found.has(str)) dupes.add(str);
  else found.add(str);
}
const result = [...found]
  .filter(str => !dupes.has(str))
  .map(JSON.parse);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried that with my example and I still see the duplicated value for some reason, but I will try that again later

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" to see the code in my answer working - as you can see, all the duplicate 1s get removed.